# Please Help Identify this Connector

Tags: identification

My Calix ONT does not have a standard 5.5x2.1 DC Barrel plug. It instead has this unique connector. It looks like Molex, but it's far smaller. At first I thought I could just use some jumper plugs; but this is keyed, so standard jumper plugs don't fit.

I'm looking to find this plug, so that I can splice it into a POE adapter and power my ONT through POE, instead of through mains power.[image]

Comment: It looks like one of Molex's Fit series connectors. Maybe micro-fit? What are the dimensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connector is a Molex Micro-Fit 3.0 Receptacle, specifically either part [430250810](https://www.molex.com/en-us/products/part-detail/430250810) or [430250800](https://www.molex.com/en-us/products/part-detail/430250800) (can't tell which, they differ only in UL flammability rating).

[image: Connector Image from Manufacturer]

<sup>Source: [Molex Product Page](https://www.molex.com/en-us/products/part-detail/430250810)</sup>

The pitch between pins is 3mm which is smaller than the more common mini-fit series. Notice also they use a different keying design for the micro-fit series which matches exactly with the pattern on your connector.

Answer (score 1):

Since only two wires appear to used, cut the cord, put any DC power jack socket on the end with the plug, and a corresponding DC power plug to the supply end, such as [these inline connectors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01J1WZENK). That would allow the device to be used with standard power supplies with DC plug, or with a home-made supply. Bonus: you'll not wear out the existing non-standard connector by frequent connection and disconnection.

BTW, if you *do* use connectors with screw terminals, put a rubber boot or shrink tubing over the bare terminals.